# Retornar consulta na mesma página

Tags: php, html

Preciso fazer uma consulta ao Banco e retornar o valor das variáveis na mesma página `PHP`. Mas nem o teste para tentar entender a lógica funcionou:

```
<html>
<form name="registar" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">

sua form bLA BLA BLA

<input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit"  value="Enviar registo" />
</form>

<?
if (!$_POST['submit']) {

echo "bla bla bla SEU nome, pass";

} else {

echo "AGUARDANDO";

}
?>

</html>
```

Nesse caso ele só entra no "AGUARDANDO".

Alguém pode me dar uma ideia?

Comment: A negação está invertendo o resultado, se tem valor(true) negue ele, logo cai no else, pode fazer um teste deixe o value vazio vai cair no if.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Altere a condição do seu `if` para algo assim:

```
<html>

    <form name="registar" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="oculto" value="teste">
        <input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit"  value="Enviar registo" />
    </form>

    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        var_dump($_POST);
    } else {
        echo "AGUARDANDO";
    }
    ?>

</html>
```

O [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.isset.php) verifica se existe o `$_POST['submit']` da forma que está ele sempre irá para a condição falsa.

Comment: Exatamente isso, MUITO OBRIGADO!

Comment: Só pra complementar, repare @Diego que você usou apenas `<?` para escrever php, dependendo da versão do servidor dessa forma o servidor nao vai interpretar. Use sempre `<?php` para iniciar código php assim como o @gmsantos usou. Fica a dica para não ter problemas futuros.

Comment: Bem observado @Skywalker. Em evite o uso de short tags para não ter problemas futuros. Acredito que exista por aqui algumas perguntas com problemas relacionados a isso.